# How to go through elements of hetero-tuple (like foreach)

Tags: c#

I would like to go through elements of a tuple of elements of different types, and the tuple's size is dynamic (it can change like that of a `List<>`).

eg., `var upl = ("toor", 't', true, false, 0, 1, 0e9, 1e9);`

How can I enumerate or go through `upl` with something like `foreach(dynamic current in upl)` ?

Do I need to implement a tuple that implements `IEnumerable` or something like this ? How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access them through reflection.

```
var upl = ("toor", 't', true, false, 0, 1, 0e9, 1e9);
var fields = upl.GetType().GetFields();
foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
{
    var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(upl);
}
```

You can also access them by casting your tuple to `ITuple` (thanks @Aluan Haddad):

```
var ituple = (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ITuple) upl;
for (int i = 0; i < ituple.Length; i++)
{
    var value = ituple.Item[i];
}
```

Comment: You can also do that without using reflection. [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ITuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple?view=netframework-4.8)